# Can I find Geometry Nodes in Blender 2.91?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, node-editor, geometry, geometry-nodes

I am new to geometry nodes and don't know whether they're in Blender 2.91 or not.

If not, can I add them into 2.91 somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Geometry Nodes are new in Blender 2.92 and implemented in there by default. You cannot load them into Blender 2.91 as an Add-on.

Comment: ... and if it's _learning_ you're going for, 2.93 alpha makes it much easier. You can use the spreadsheet to get a clearer picture of what's happening.